# qtcreator customize getters and setters

Tags: qt-creator

I have lots of member variables in my file i.e. `int m_member_var`, when I hit alt+enter to auto generate the getters/setters, it give me the setter`void setMember_var(...)`. But I need `set_member_var(...)`.  Is there a way to change the template?
I'm using Qtcreator 3.0.1

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of QtCreator?

Comment: tell me how u do it in 3.4.1 then

Comment: I don't think you can; not sure though.  You are not following the Qt naming conventions.